# How to configure Alexa Skills Kit trigger for a lambda function via CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, alexa-skills-kit

I am developing an Alexa skill and would like to use CloudFormation to deploy infrastructure for my skill.

So far IAM role, policy and lambda function deployment work fine. What I'm missing is a trigger from Alexa Skill Kit for my lambda function.

At the moment I have to manually create this trigger in the AWS console:

[image: AWS Console UI to add Alexa Skills Kit trigger for a lambda function]

Or via CLI:

```
aws lambda add-permission --function-name DeutscheDeklinationLambdaFunction --statement-id 1 --action lambda:invokeFunction --principal alexa-appkit.amazon.com --region eu-west-1
```

But I'd prefer to configure this trigger via CloudFormation. I think it should be [`https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-eventsourcemapping.html`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-eventsourcemapping.html), but I could not find how to implement this for Alexa Skills Kit.

Answer (score 3):

A classic, three minutes after posting a question I've found an answer on my own.

It appears that "trigger" in this case is actually a lambda permission for the function to be invoked by Alexa Skills Kit. So it can be configured as follows:

```
  DeutscheDeklinationLambdaFunctionPermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties: 
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      FunctionName: !GetAtt DeutscheDeklinationLambdaFunction.Arn
      Principal: alexa-appkit.amazon.com
      EventSourceToken: !Ref AppId
```

`FunctionsName` is ARN of the function, `EventSourceToken` is the id of the skill.

Comment: Can you share the final cloudformation template that you're using for deployment?

Comment: @thedreamsaver Siehe https://github.com/highsource/declension-alexa-skill-lambda/blob/master/templates/DeutscheDeklination.template

Comment: Doesn't the FunctionName need to be something like `!Ref DeutscheDeklinationLambdaFunction` instead of getting the ARN?

Comment: @trademark Several name formats (including ARN) are allowed:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-permission.html#cfn-lambda-permission-functionname

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to do it in typescript for AWS CDK (cloud development kit).

```
import { ServicePrincipal } from '@aws-cdk/aws-iam';
...
MyLambda.addPermission('alexa-skills-kit-trigger', {
  principal: new ServicePrincipal('alexa-appkit.amazon.com'),
  action: 'lambda:invokeFunction',
});
```

Documentation:

[@aws-cdk/aws-iam](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-iam-readme.html)

[@aws-cdk_aws-lambda.Permission](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-lambda.Permission.html)

Comment: Better add `eventSourceToken` in the Permission. Otherwise any Alexa skills can invoke this Lambda function.